# PDF to TIFF tool not displaying image on ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, pdf

I am trying to display a PDF map of London tube station on ArcMap, so I can geo reference it with co-ordinates.

I am using the **PDF to TIFF** tool.

The picture below, indicates I am saving the file in the same place and as a **tif** file.

[image]

Whenever I do this I get this error message (shown below) and nothing is displayed.

[image]

When I click the error code, it provides this information below

[image]

I have coordinates, for the PDF which once it loads into ArcMap I can georeference it, and export the file into a form readable by CAD. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: There are several ArcGIS Online Sources for the London Underground in True Geography like https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8a567ebac15748d39a747649a2e86cf4 - what is the source of the PDF and why do you need that conversion?

Comment: The london tube map, was just an example. I am not sure of the exact source of the PDF i have been given and I am required to convert the pdf into tiff to load onto arc GIS then save it as a ipeg file to use in cad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is triggered when the input PDF does not have any spatial context.

For example, if we use a PDF that was created using a GIS platform with some spatial association, the conversion will be there without any warning.

I tested the conversion:

1. Received no warning when using a PDF exported out of ArcGIS Pro and converted to TIFF using the Tool in ArcMap.
2. Received a warning when using a random PDF without any spatial association.

**Note:** *We will still get the output even if we receive a warning.*

This is expected behavior and if the PDF contains no spatial information, the output TIFF is created without GeoTIFF tags.

[001752: The PDF document contains no spatial information.](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01751-01775-001752.htm)

As a workaround you can try using the Online conversion of PDF to JPG/TIFF.

There are multiple options avaiable for the same, one of the best is to use the My geodata Converter.

[**MyGeodata Converter**](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my only query is that if you still get the output even if you receive a warning or not, when I use 'mygeodata converter' to convert my non-spatial data pdf' i get the error code 'No spatial data were recognized in your uploaded data. We are sorry.
Make sure you have uploaded all relevant files of the dataset.' Am I doing something wrong, or Have I not understood what to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ESRI (UK) arcgis online service (there are others)

> https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/WQ9KVmV6xGGMnCiQ/arcgis/rest/services/TubeMap/MapServer?cacheKey=88919ac5051b9bd1

In QGIS or **ArcGIS Desktop** add the url
and export to dxf.

[image]